# jquery show an element on mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As the title says i want the element to fade in when the mouse hovers over it.

```
<div class="carousel-item">

    <div class="carousel-item-top">
        <img class="img-responsive" alt="a" src="carousel/crsl-img-1.png">
        <div class="carousel-item-top-hover"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="inline-block carousel-item-bottom">
        <h5 class="pull-left">Awesome Design</h5>
        <span class="pull-right share">
            74
            <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
            <span class="v-sep"></span>
            <i class="fa fa-share"></i>
        </span>
    </div>

</div>
```

The css for the item i hope to become visible

```
.carousel-item-top-hover{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #219fd1;
    opacity: 0.85;
    display: none;
}
```

And one of the javascript variants i was hoping to be able to handle it

```
$(".carousel-item-top").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this)(".carousel-item-top-hover").fadeIn('slow')
});
```

Comment: Why aren't you using CSS3 for this? It looks like the perfect situation.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia He seems to want elements to react to changes in other elements' state. To me, this seems like a problem for jQuery.

Comment: It looks like he wants `child` elements to change for the parent's hover or hover on the same element from the naming (appending `-hover`), which can be done in CSS3. But it could be about a completely unrelated element (so jquery there). It's actually pretty vague, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @morgred please clarify: do you want the element to show when `carosel-item-top` is hovered over (reflected in your code)? Or do you want it like you asked (when itself is hovered over)

Comment: i did an edit because it seems i didnt include the html right the first time. sorry for the confusion i caused

Answer (score 1):

Note: What you said doesn't reflect your code that you tried (you said you wanted the element to be shown when the mouse is over IT, but the code makes it show when something else is hovered over.) I'm assuming you meant what your code says.

The proper handler is [$(el).mouseover()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/).

```
$(".carousel-item-top").mouseover(function () {
    $(".carousel-item-top-hover").fadeIn('slow')
});
```

you almost had it, but you had a superfluous `(this)`.

Comment: Yes, but `fadeIn` won't work on a partially opaque element. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20928178/2535504

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara jQuery's fadeIn automatically sets the display to something other than none like inline, inline-block, block, etc.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean. I'm not sure what he wants anymore.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I see what you mean. Why set display to none and then set the opacity? (P.S. Please use @. It's just by chance that I saw your comment.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't hover over something that isn't displayed. The mouse can't hover over something that isn't there. You might want to set visibility to hidden instead of display none. Then there is still space where you can hover over it.

```
visibility: hidden;
```

If that doesn't work, set the opacity to 0 and then animate the opacity to .85 when you mouse enter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `fadeIn`, use `fadeTo` like this:

```
$(".carousel-item-top-hover").fadeTo('slow', 1);
```

Instead of slow, you can also provide an integer for the speed in milliseconds.